# Create repeatative springboot controllers from configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

***Dynamic Parent Controller***

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
public abstract class RealtimeController<T> {
    public abstract RealtimeService<T> getService();

    @PostMapping(value = "/find")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<T>> find(@RequestBody T entity) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(getService().findAllByKey(entity));
    }
}
```

***Dynamic Service***

```
public abstract class RealtimeService<T> {
    public abstract RealtimeRepository<T> getRepository();

    public Iterable<T> findAllByKey(T entity) {
        return getRepository().findAll(
                Example.of(
                        entity,
                        ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("_class"))
        );
    }

}
```

***Child Controller1***

```
@Api(tags = "Child1")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/child1")
@Slf4j
public class Child1Controller extends RealtimeController<Child1> {

    @Autowired
    private Child1Service child1Service;

    @Override
    public RealtimeService<Child1> getService(){
        return child1Service;
    }
}
```

***Child Controller2***

```
@Api(tags = "Child2")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/child2")
@Slf4j
public class Child2Controller extends RealtimeController<Child2> {

    @Autowired
    private Child2Service child2Service;

    @Override
    public RealtimeService<Child2> getService(){
        return child2Service;
    }
}
```

**Question1:**

*I have 10 of these child controllers. Is there a way to dynamically create them from some config? The only difference between every child controller is the Model, tag and endpoint. My idea was to read these config from a property file and generate these controllers dynamically somehow. is it possible?*

***application.yaml***

```
controllers:
- name: Child1
  endpoint: /api/v1/child1
  model: Child1 
- name: Child2
  endpoint: /api/v1/child2
  model: Child2
```

**Question2:**

*Is there another better way to achieve similar results without code duplication ?*

Comment: What is a signature of `findAllByKey`?

Comment: I'm curious about how it works. `find(@RequestBody T entity)` will be turned into `find(@RequestBody Object entity)` after compilation. Possibly some `spring` magic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```java
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/{childtype}")
public class RealtimeController {
    public RealtimeService getService(String childtype){
        return map.get(childtype);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/find")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Object>> find(@PathVariable("childtype") String childtype, @RequestBody Object entity) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(getServiceByType(childtype).findAllByKey(entity));
    }
}
```

All you need now is to fill map with instances of service.

Comment: I thought of this. in this case, springfox won’t register the controllers separately, will create only one endpoint. Plus the object type is dynamic here. :/